# Проблема с добавлением строки в таблицу

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток, форумчане.

В html есть таблица с двумя столбиками, я написал js, для добавления строки в таблицу:

Js:

```
function func_table_without_forma()
{
    var table = document.getElementById('tabl_one_without_forma');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = '<td><input name="edit_in_1" type="text" size="40"></td>\n\
                    <td><input name="edit_in_2" type="text" size="40"></td>';
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
};
```

Все работает...  
Потом, я таблицу (в html) вставил в форму:

Js:

```
function func_table_with_forma()
{
    var table = document.forma7.tabl_one_with_forma;
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = '<td><input name="edit_in_1" type="text" size="40"></td>\n\
                    <td><input name="edit_in_2" type="text" size="40"></td>';
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
};
```

и где-то здесь происходит ошибка.

Где я допустил ошибку?  
Спасибо за ответ...

P.S.  
html:

```
<form name="forma7">
            <table id="tabl_one_with_forma" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td  width="20%">111</td>   <!--   height="59" -->
                        <td width="50%">22772</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>   
            </table>
            <br><br>
            <button onclick="func_table_with_forma()"><b>with</b>_forma</button> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function func_table_with_forma() {
//var table = document.forma7.tabl_one_with_forma;
var table = document.getElementById('tabl_one_with_forma');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML = '<td><input name="edit_in_1" type="text" size="40"></td>\n\
                <td><input name="edit_in_2" type="text" size="40"></td>';
var td = document.createElement('td');
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
return false;  // что-бы не форма не отсылалась - возвращаем false
};
```

и в html:

```
button onclick="return func_table_with_forma();"><b>with</b>_forma</button>
```

Comment: I. @boris_U, извиняюсь (я недавно  сел за JS),   
а как получить текст ошибки (для написания я использую NetBeans)?   
II. А если в html несколько форм, в которых таблицы имеют одинаковый идентификатор, (я насчет "//var table = document.forma7.tabl_one_with_forma;")?

Comment: @Konstantin78, идентификатор с конкретным именем на странице может быть только один, если это нарушать то скрипты начнут работать нестабильно :)

Comment: @Konstantin78, В первом вопросе - `try{}catch(){}`, во втором - ID должен быть уникален в пространстве DOM. Иначе никто не может предсказать поведение любой функции, которая оперирует DOM'ом.

Comment: Да о уникальности, я в курсе, но я думал, если ID находится в форме, то я могу в записи "document.forma7.tabl_one_with_forma" основываться на форму.   
По первому вопросу @TheDoctor, **вставка ячеек** - я так хочу попробывать сделать вставку записи в таблицу, а затем ее сохранения в БД (чтоб не делать дополнительного обработчика ("control", "view" в kohana), т.к. нужно вставить только два значения. А вариант добавлени через **"element.innerHTML"** нашел на одном из форумов.

Answer (score 1):

Было бы просто чудесно, приложи вы тут текст ошибки.

Этот код взбесился и повесил jsFiddle.

1) Зачем вставка ячеек через `element.innerHTML`, а затем создание пустой ячейки и её добавление?

2) У через свойства доступны `name=''`, но не `id=''`, поэтому форму-то он находит, а id внутри - нет. Тут-то всё и летит.

P. S. `return false` делать не нужно, используй `event.preventDefault()` [[разница](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Folegorestov.ru%2Fjs%2Freturn_false_vs_preventdefault%2F&ei=cTHuVPdBip_KA6O2giA&usg=AFQjCNFwe9TqiNC3k7l4ZgfyYFNHcp-pEA&sig2=BL_hWZupNoMhE-9T2GvuNQ&bvm=bv.86956481,d.bGQ)].

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Ljdwjr/ в подтверждение варианта @TheDoctor с preventDefault(), добавил к варианту автора 1 строчку

Comment: круто! теперь отсылка формы не происходит из-за:
Error: ReferenceError: event is not defined


тогда-уж надо вызывать эту функцию с параметром event


onclick="func_table_with_forma(event);"


и саму ее определять как :

func_table_with_forma(e) {
///
e.preventDefault();

}

Comment: event - это системный объект, он всегда есть.  
У меня пример работает (что логично), на jsFiddle тоже. Что-то у вас не так.

Comment: судя по "объяснению", ничего страшного, кроме потери понтов, в использовании "return false" - нет.

Comment: @boris_U, страшного - нет, правильного - да.  
Всплытие - нужная вещь, её ненужно отменять, ведь мы не знаем что ещё захочет автор навесить внутри?

Comment: @boris_U, вариант автора с `return false` работать не захотел, это уже заставляет задуматься, а правильно ли здесь писать это выражение

Comment: @TheDoctor, оок. как насчет этого:
http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro#smysl-return-false-iz-obrabotchika

"Возвращение return false из обработчика события предотвращает действие браузера по умолчанию, но не останавливает всплытие."

Откройте js-консоль в браузере и увидите там эту ошибку